# SVN, setting up directories for external source projects

Tags: svn

I have a project that relies on a some custom modifications to some open source software. I'd like to keep it all under version control.

I am currently doing something like this:

myapp/
myapp/external/dependency1/
myapp/external/dependency2/
myapp/external/dependency3/

The problem is that that when I do a ./configure / make to compile the external dependencies, SVN becomes 'polluted' with a lot of small files that show up whenever you do SVN status. Other developers are committing temporary and machine-specific build files as well, which is annoying.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to better arange my repository so that I can still do a ./configure and make, but while ideally preventing svn from tracking all the temporary and intermediate build files (ideally they should not even show up in svn status).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [svn:ignore](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm) to prevent svn from tracking unneeded files.